# ASP.Net Tab Control: Load Content on Click via Separate ASPX Files

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, lazy-loading, tabcontrol

I'm looking for a way to use a tab control such that there is a single `TabPanel`, and when a tab is clicked the `TabPanel` is populated from a separate ASPX file. If I have three tabs, then tab1.aspx is used for content when tab one is selected, tab2.aspx is used for content when tab two is selected, and so on.

I've found a number of tutorials on cramming everything into a single page. I've also read [How To: Make Tab control panels load "on-demand"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sburke/archive/2007/06/13/how-to-make-tab-control-panels-load-on-demand.aspx) (which uses hidden controls). But I have not come across loading a partial view via a link or postback.

Would anyone know of a link to an ASP.Net video or well explained tutorial/blog?

Jeff

Comment: You should use [UserControls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb3w5b53.aspx) instead of separate aspx-files. You can then [lazy-load](http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/07/how_to_lazyload_tabpanels_with.html) them when you want.

Comment: Btw, i've edited your question, i assume you meant TabPanel instead of ContentPanel.

Comment: "... TabPanel instead of ContentPanel" - No problem Tim. I knew I need some sort of Tab, Update (Ajax), or Content panel.

Comment: if you really need the aspx files and can't use UserControls as Tim suggested, you can always use the "ugly" iframes

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that it is possible.

But I suggest that you combine all of your aspx files in one (you can place each file in PlaceHolder or Panel) and then make them visible when you need it.

Comment: I'm trying to stay away from this design. Its a mess in practice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use IFRAME for different page content load.

On press Tab1 you have to load Tab1.aspx. For that you have to IFrame to Load Content. If your Content is static then you can get content by System.IO.ReadFile(); and if you have dynamic content then you can use Iframe or User Control to load.

You can also Implement the Multiview to approach your way and put it in Update panel and design the multiview as TAB panel.